# How to Record Audio and Video using React Native App (Without Expo)

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Is there a way to create App in react native which can be used to record audio and video and save same file on both Android and iOS Devices using App?

Please help me as I am stuck.
Thank You.

Comment: There are number of libraries available to do that but it will be helpful if you provide some specific information about the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use 3 library maintained by the React Native community. 
react-native-camera (for recording videos)
react-native-video (for playing video)
react-native-audio-toolkit (for recording and playing audio)

To record an audio

```
    import {
      Recorder,
    } from 'react-native-audio-toolkit';

    // function to start recorder
    this.recorder = new Recorder(‘filename.mp4’).record();
```

To record video and play it, there is a really good blog post in medium

https://medium.com/react-native-training/uploading-videos-from-react-native-c79f520b9ae1

For more example, please check examples in the github pages for each library

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit